# Using Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a query in SQL Server to loop through the associates and count how many transactions they processed.

```
select 
    Id, submitter_name, submitter_id,
    count(*) as numberOfTickets
from
    Tickets 
where 
    created_at between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-14' 
    and ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + 'tickets' + ',%'
group by 
    Id, submitter_name, submitter_id;
```

This results shows the associates name over and over with one transaction. I am trying to count and show there name once with the total count for `numberOfTickets`.

I am not sure where I am going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please supply some sample data and expected results? Also, your `WHERE` clause `',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + 'tickets' + ',%'` very strongly suggests you're storing delimited data in your table. This is a really bad idea; I would strongly suggest redesigning your database to a more normalised format. (Or at least using a string splitter, and not `LIKE` with a leading wild card, but a redesign would be a far better idea).

Comment: Are you just looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that `Id` is the Id of the ticket. You don't want that included in your select and groupby because that is the number you want to count.

```
select submitter_name, submitter_id,
       count(*) as numberOfTickets
from  Tickets 
where created_at between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-14' and
      ',' + tags + ',' like '%,' + 'tickets' + ',%'
group by submitter_name, submitter_id;
```

As a side note, for the love of all that is holy, don't store your tags like that. Your RDBMS will hate you for it. Use a many-to-many relationship.